# Known property? Maximum radius of connected induced subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

I was wondering if the following graph property has a name and has been researched:
Consider any connected induced subgraph $H \subseteq G$.
Then $r(G)$ denotes the maximum radius of any such $H$.

I think it is an interesting property since graphs with bounded $r(G)$ are closed under taking induced subgraphs whereas graphs of bounded radius are not.

Edit: The reason why I am only interested in *induced* subgraphs is that it otherwise would degenerate to the length of the longest (not necessarily) induced path.

Comment: What happens when H = G? Assuming G is connected.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly. Consider the example where G is a wheel of size n+1, then G has radius 1. When you consider the induced subgraph without the Apex it has radius n/2. Hence r(G) >=n/2.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I somehow thought you were talking about minimum diameter.

Comment: Would that be decided by the longest induced cycle/path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The property $\Pi_r$, defined as containing exactly the graphs $G$ such that every induced subgraph $H$ of $G$ has diameter at most $r$, is the same as the class of graphs that do not contain a $P_{r+2}$ as induced subgraph, where the $P_{r+2}$ is the path on $r+2$ vertices.

The equivalence can be seen as follows. The two degree-one vertices in the $P_{r+2}$ have a distance of $r+1$. Hence, if $G$ contains a subgraph isomorphic to the $P_{r+2}$, then $G$ does not fulfill $\Pi_r$. Conversely, if $G$ does not fulfill $\Pi_r$, then $G$ has an induced subgraph $H$ containing two vertices $u$ and $v$ such that the distance between $u$ and $v$ in $H$ is at least $r+1$. Take the vertex set $P$ of a shortest path between $u$ and $v$ in $H$. Since $P$ is a shortest path, $G[P]$ is an induced path, that is, it is isomorphic to some $P_\ell$. Since $u$ and $v$ have distance at least $r+1$ in $G[P]$, we have $\ell\ge r+2$. Hence $G$ contains $P_{r+2}$ as an induced subgraph.

Comment: This is a good characterisation! Do you happen to know some if it connected to other graph characteristics or has interesting structural/algorithmical implications?

Comment: There are lots of results on graphs without induced $P_4$ (which are called co-graphs) and on graphs without induced $P_5$; see for instance http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_151.html and http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_396.html

Comment: The Wikipedia article on induced paths refers to a quite a bunch of results on graphs with bounded induced path length: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_path

Comment: The "detour number" is what I have been looking for. It even has a connection to treedepth. Thanks to all participants!